# How to use the PayPal Live and Sandbox at the same time

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a website that has two versions: live(mywebsite.com) and dev (dev.mywebsite.com). "Live" for real users and "dev" for development process.

So, I want to use PayPal Live mode on the live website and PayPal sendbox for testing on the "dev" subdomain. How can I organize this process?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which PayPal product you are using.

Ideally if you just make sure that if you are calling a paypal api in sandbox it will have "sandbox" in the url..Also you can create sandbox account with a different email address that also will help in distinction.